# Gambler tosses coin PGF

Tags: statistics

A gambler tosses a coin repeatedly until it comes up tails. He gets £1 for each head that comes up before that happens, and pays back £1 for the tail. Find the probability generating function for his winnings and show that it can be written in the form $\frac {1}{t(2-t)}$. By differentiating this function, show that it is a fair game, find the variance, and determine whether the distribution is positively or negatively skewed.

I have $G(t)=(1/2)t+(1/2t)$ but I can't get it in the form shown above. I have proven that it is a fair game by showing G'(1)=0 and found the variance = 2. How can I show whether it is positively or negatively skewed?

Comment: How did you arrive at this expression for G?

Comment: @Did $(1/2)t^1+(1/2)t^{-1}$

Comment: Quite unrelated.

Comment: @Did How then should I do it?

Comment: You should first determine all the possible winnings, then compute the probability of each.

Comment: @Did Are all possible winnings £1, £0 and £-1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7386/discussion-between-user52187-and-did)

Comment: Read again: the possible winnings are -1, 0, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6, ...

Comment: @Did if this goes on forever then $G(t)=(1/2)t^{-1}+(1/4)+(1/2)t+(1/4)t^2+(1/8)t^3...=(1/2t)+(1/4)+(t/2)(1/1-(t/2))$

Answer (score 0):

If the first tail appears after $n\geqslant0$ heads, the gambler's fortune $X$ is $n-1$. This happens with probability $2^{-n-1}$, hence
$$
G(t)=\mathbb E(t^X)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}t^{n-1}2^{-n-1}\stackrel{[s=t/2]}{=}\frac1{2t}\sum_{n\geqslant0}s^n=\frac1{2t}\frac1{1-s}=\frac1{t(2-t)}.
$$
To compute the successive derivatives of $G$, one might want to rewrite it as
$$
G(t)=\frac1{2t}+\frac1{2(2-t)},
$$
which yields, for example,
$$
G'(t)=-\frac1{2t^2}+\frac1{2(2-t)^2},
$$
hence,
$$
\mathbb E(X)=G'(1)=0.
$$
The computations of the variance and the skewness are similar.

Comment: Is it true that the skewness is given by the third central moment? If so how do I calculate that from the PGF?

Comment: Wait, you are asking a question involving the skewness of a random variable and you do not know the definition?

Comment: I know the definition but I don't know how to calculate it. I suggested the third central moment because that is one of the ways that you can do it, but I don't think that is the best way.